# Sorting through 4k-5k rows, to hide some of the rows

Tags: excel, vba

How do I speed up this functioning VBA code? It takes a long time, around five minutes to sort through 4k-5k rows, to hide some of the rows.

The macro sorts through Column A, sorting through the names and comparing it to a list in Sheet1. If the name matches the list in sheet1, it will hide the row.

```vb
Sub FilterNameDuplicate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Dim iListCount As Integer
    Dim iCtr As Integer
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim D As Long
    a = Worksheets("Default").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For c = 1 To a
        b = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For D = 1 To b
            If StrComp(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(D, "A"), (Worksheets("Default").Cells(c, "G")), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Worksheets("Default").Rows(c).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main slow down is do to nested looping.  Using a Collection or Dictionary for quicker lookups will speed up your code 100 times.

```
Sub FilterNameDuplicate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Rem Unhide all the rows
    Worksheets("Default").UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    Dim Keys As Collection
    Set Keys = GKeys
    
    Dim Key As String
    
    Dim Target As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Default")
        Set Target = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G"))
    End With
    
    If Target Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Range"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        Key = UCase(Cell.Value)
        On Error Resume Next
        Key = Keys(Key)
        Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = Err.Number <> 0
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    
    Rem We no longer need to turn ScreenUpdating back on
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Function GKeys() As Collection
    Set GKeys = New Collection
    Dim Key As String
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Key = UCase(Data(r, 1))
        On Error Resume Next
        GKeys.Add Key:=Key, Item:=""
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    
End Function
```

Comment: Hey @TinMan, code gets the job partially done in 5 seconds. It does filter out some names, but there are some names that are being left out from being filtered, whilst at the same time the macro has hidden some of the other names that dont belong in the filter list. The end result ends up being wrong, because some of the names that are supposed to be hidden aren't, and some of the hidden names aren't supposed to. Currently end result shows 200++ rows of data, which is wrong, as there should be upwards of 1100++ rows left unhidden.

Comment: @remy I updated my answer.  I was using my collection wrong.

Comment: Works well, and works quick. Thanks for this!

Comment: Hey @TinMan, there is some issues with the code still. upon closer inspection, a few names are still not being hidden. Any fixes?

Comment: @remy No way for me to know.  If you send me the file at tinmanse@aol.com, I'll look at it.  Have you checked for extra spaces in the data?

Comment: its alright now. Somehow restarting my computer managed to get the code working perfectly fine, and in record time of 5 seconds as well! thanks!

Comment: @remy Glad to hear it.

Comment: Hey @TinMan, added a few names to the names needed to be removed and the macro doesnt hide them at all. It hides those that were already there beforehand though.

Answer (score 3):

All of your accesses to the worksheet really slows things down.
Much faster to use VBA arrays.

You can eliminate some of the looping by using the `Range.Find` method to determine if there are duplicates of the names on `Default` in `Sheet1`.

We collect the non-duplicated names (in a Collection) and then create an array to use as the argument for the `Range.Filter` method (which will effectively hide the entire row).

Accordingly:

*Code edited to run faster using `Match` function*

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterNameDuplicate()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
    Dim v1 As Variant, vD As Variant, r1 As Range, rD As Range
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim R As Range, I As Long, arrNames() As String

With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsD = .Worksheets("Default")
End With

With ws1
    Set r1 = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    v1 = r1
End With

With wsD
    Set rD = Range(.Cells(1, 7), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
    vD = rD
End With

'collect names on Default that are not on Sheet1
Set col = New Collection
With Application
    For I = 2 To UBound(vD, 1)
        If .WorksheetFunction.IsError(.Match(vD(I, 1), v1, 0)) Then col.Add vD(I, 1)
    Next I
End With

'Filter to include those names
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If wsD.FilterMode Then wsD.ShowAllData

ReDim arrNames(1 To col.Count)
For I = 1 To col.Count
    arrNames(I) = col(I)
Next I

rD.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=arrNames, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Code works, but did not filter out certain names that are supposed to be hidden. thanks! but this is slower than my original macro. Is it due to my excel sheet?

Current stats are: 4775 used rows, 4773 rows of data to sort through.(1st n 2nd row is ignored.)

Filter list composes of 307 unique names, could be added onto it in the future.

please take a look and give me your opinion. I unfortunately cannot send the data due to company regulations, but i hope this will aid. Any other info you require, you could ask and i will try my best to provide.

Comment: @remy There is no need to share confidential data. However, there is a need for you to provide a data example that reproduces the problem -- both the slow running and the mismatches. Just use made-up data. (One of us would have to make something up, and that should be you).  If you have formulas in your worksheet, try disabling calculations first. I am surprised this is slower than your original.

Comment: @remy You could try the latest edit. On my smaller sample, using `Match` against the VBA array decreased the run time significantly.

Comment: Hey, tried this. Works perfectly fine, thanks so much. However, it is slightly slower than the other offered answer, but i really wish i could give the both of you the answer tab. Thanks so much even with the explanation, this will be really helpful for my project.

Answer (score 2):

Trying adding in this, it speeds up by turning off screen updating, events, animations etc, this should speed it up a bit!

At the start of your code add in this sub

```
Call TurnOffCode
```

At the end of your code add in this sub

```
Call TurnOnCode
```

This is what they should both look like

```
Sub TurnOffCode() 'Used to turn off settings to make workbook run faster
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Set calculations to manual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen updating
Application.EnableEvents = False 'Turns off events
Application.EnableAnimations = False 'Turns off animations
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False 'Turns off display status bar
Application.PrintCommunication = False 'Turns off print communications
End Sub

Sub TurnOnCode() 'Used to turn settings back on to normal
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Set calculations to automatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating
Application.EnableEvents = True 'Turns on events
Application.EnableAnimations = True 'Turns on animations
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True 'Turns on display status bar
Application.PrintCommunication = True 'Turns on print communications
End Sub
```

Comment: @TinMan with all of those applied there will be a clear difference, I use them all the time and it saves several minutes.

Comment: I have to eat crow on this one.  You are correct.  I still think the main slow down is the lookups but  turning off `Application.Calculation` with 40K formulas made a huge impact.  I was mistaking to assume that hiding rows would not trigger recalculations.  +1 more if I could.

Comment: This provides an impact towards my other macros. Thanks for the help!